# Как называется такой тип приложения?

Tags: кроссплатформенность

Есть программы например "MongoDB Compass".

- Как называются приложения с подобным браузерным/веб интерфейсом?
- С применением каких языков можно написать такое приложение?
- В каких популярных IDE можно создавать подобные приложения?

Comment: Если вопрос про кроссплатформенность, то там самый обыкновенный Electron

Comment: Нет вопрос про интерфейс, + про то откуда там HTML в интерфейсе.

Comment: Из Electron'а :) Но как именно разрабатывают приложения на Electron'е, я не в курсе (ибо я ненавижу Electron:)

Comment: Для кого то Electron самый обычный, а кто то впервые слышит и не понимает что это вообще такое....

Comment: Кратко, Electron — это такой Google Chrome с единственным сайтом внутри, другим (небраузерным) интерфейсом и доступом к ОС у этого единственного сайта. Подробно не знаю)